# collapsing levels of a factor using fct_collapse form forcats when the levels are integers

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I have a tricky problem. I have a factor where the labels of the factor are numbers. I want to collapse several levels into one and keep the other levels intact

I tried

```
fct_collapse(factor(c(1,3,6,9)),
             `1` = "1",
             `3` = "3",
             group_other = "3+")
```

But I get this error.

```
Error in if (group_other) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I tried putting the levels on the left side in quotations but same error.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The `group_other` is deprecated, perhaps use `other_level`

```
library(forcats)
fct_collapse(factor(c(1,3,6,9)),
             `1` = "1",
             `3` = "3",
             other_level = "3+")
[1] 1  3  3+ 3+
Levels: 1 3 3+
```

Comment: Ah yes I see @akrun. My version of forcats is old. The new one mentions that group_other is deprecated. Thank you.